# How to identify front and back cameras with mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() on iOS 11 Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile-safari, getusermedia

I'm using [getUserMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) to capture a camera stream on iOS 11's Safari. When I get the list of cameras using the [MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) API, the labels are blank. Is there a way to reliably determine which camera is pointed in which direction?

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(function(devices) {
    devices.forEach(function(device) {
        if(device.kind === 'videoinput') {
            console.log(device);
            // Labels for both cameras are blank:
            // MediaDeviceInfo { deviceId: "123ABC", groupId: "", kind: "videoinput", label: "" }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you calling getUserMedia() prior to enumerateDevices() ?

Comment: The problem may lie within your granted user permissions here

Answer (score 0):

The docs make it sound like a user may have to grant permissions to give labeled camera data.

It says:

> This might produce
>
> ```
> videoinput: id = csO9c0YpAf274OuCPUA53CNE0YHlIr2yXCi+SqfBZZ8=
> audioinput: id = RKxXByjnabbADGQNNZqLVLdmXlS0YkETYCIbg+XxnvM=
> audioinput: id = r2/xw1xUPIyZunfV1lGrKOma5wTOvCkWfZ368XCndm0=
> ```
>
> or if one or more MediaStreams are active or ***persistent permissions*** are granted:
>
> ```
> videoinput: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in) 
> id=csO9c0YpAf274OuCPUA53CNE0YHlIr2yXCi+SqfBZZ8=
> audioinput: default (Built-in Microphone)
> id=RKxXByjnabbADGQNNZqLVLdmXlS0YkETYCIbg+XxnvM=
> audioinput: Built-in Microphone id=r2/xw1xUPIyZunfV1lGrKOma5wTOvCkWfZ368XCndm0=
> ```

To me this implies that the issue might lie in user permissions.